# How to join array of objects in javascript and then insert into html element

Tags: javascript, object

http://jsfiddle.net/Mw22G/2/

```
    var link1 = '<a href="/path/file.html">Link'+i+'</a>';

    var link2 = document.createElement("a");
    var linkText = document.createTextNode("Link"+i);
    link2.appendChild(linkText);
    link2.setAttribute('href','/path/file.html');
```

String links worked out as expected, now I want to achieve the same result for object links.
The goal was to dynamically populate a variable with a set of links and add the whole thing in one step without bothering the DOM in a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure if I understand your question fully. If you wanna avoid touching the DOM in a loop, createDocumentFragment() is the way to go.

```
var links = [
  {
    text: 'link 1',
    href: '/path/file1.html'
  },
  {
    text: 'link 2',
    href: '/path/file2.html'
  }
];

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (var i = 0, len = links.length, a, l; i < len; i++) {
  l = links[i];
  a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = l.href;
  a.innerText = l.text;
  frag.appendChild(a);
}

document.body.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: Yes this was the pure goal! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

if you do this:

```
arrLink2.push(link2.outerHTML);
```

That will give you the same output as `arrLink1` does. The values in both arrays will be the same.

If you don't need to worry about IE 8 (or you use a polyfill), you can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) instead of `join`:

```
var Link2Res = arrLink2.reduce(function (previousValue, currentValue, index/*, array */) {
    return previousValue + (index > 0 ? '<br>' : '') + currentValue.outerHTML;
}, '');
```

Comment: Great use of outerHTML, I completely forgot about it. Thanks!